# Unable to access the association inside a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a card model,

```
class Card < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :meta_sm2
  after_create :add_meta

  private

  def add_meta
    self.meta_sm2.create()
  end
end
```

After I create a `card` object, I get a `NoMethodError` which states that `create` function inside `add_meta` does not exist becase `self.meta_sm2` is nil.

```
class MetaSm2 < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Error,

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `create' for nil:NilClass
    from /Users/li-xinyang/Desktop/XX_API/app/models/card.rb:37:in `add_meta'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way of creating an associated record is by calling `create_association_name`, so use `create_meta_sm2`:

```
def add_meta
  create_meta_sm2
end
```

More info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html